# Remote storage for sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, remote-access, cloud-hosting

I'd like to upload my `SQLite` database to some remote storage to have access to my database from various computers and mobile devices programatically.

Is there a solution that enables secure solution (data won't be stolen) with good information privacy and some programming interface for various languages? (e.g. Python, C, Java in Android, etc.)?

Comment: On linux, just mount your sftp or whatever and work with it as if it was your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has an [Encryption Extension (SEE)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html).

> The SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE) is an add-on to the public domain version of SQLite that allows an application to read and write encrypted database files.

It is a commercial product, not Public Domain as SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded database which must be stored on a filesystem accessible by the client application. SQLite doesn't support multiple concurrent clients, remote access, access control, or encryption (natively.) The requirements that you list are *much* better served by a more traditional database server, such as MySQL or PostgreSQL. You can easily export SQLite data and import it into one of these databases.

If you are dead-set on using SQLite, you can try storing the database on a shared, remote, filesystem, a la Dropbox. You'll still have to worry about concurrent access and you'll lose many of speed advantages of using SQLite, but the database will be accessible from multiple machines.